# How to make a post with python and receive XML

Tags: python, xml

I know nothing about python but this task as been assigned to me. Currently I am WebClient and using a get string to receive XML back, but I need to be using POST.

I need to make the post than read the XML back, my current code:

```
    postUrl = 'http://sitetopost.net/checkduplicateemail?TransactionType=NoCharge&CampaignId=47750&SubCampaignId=6010117&BundleId=' + bundleId + '&PackageDealId=' + packageDealId + '&OrganizationId=e11b4f9e-be9a-464f-96b0-885a571e3cc9&FirstName=' + firstName + '&LastName=' + lastName + '&EmailAddress=' + email + '&Phone=' + phone + '&IPAddress=[=$Registration.IpAddress=]&Address1=' + address + '&Address2=' + address2 + '&City=' + city + '&ProvinceAbbreviation=' + state + '&PostalCode=' + postalcode + '&order_OriginatorId=6&order_OriginatorOrderIdentifier=1234567&userinfo_ProductWebUserName=&userinfo_ProductWebUserPassword='

contentTemplate = Sel.GetHtmlContentTemplateHtmlByName(path.Meme, contentPage)

    client = WebClient()
    billResponse = client.DownloadString(postUrl)
    xml = XElement.Parse(billResponse)

    Logger.Trace("XML: {0}", billResponse)
```

How can I change this into a post? Thanks!

Comment: look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Answer (score 3):

The requests library is a wonderful way to do this in python. Very simply:

```
import requests

url = #relevant url
data = #{some dictionary}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the response. Try calling the following to see what it has:

```
dir(response)
vars(response)
```